# Pass column name dynamically from frontend to SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Requirment is we have 10 column in table and in frontend presented as grid of 10 column and a search box with each.

Upon user enter a search in any one column, that column name and value should be passed into where clause.

sample Table

```
  number    agency        brand   product   ad_product  indication
  1234      salesforce    BMW      sxx       suv          E-class
  5678      apple         iphone   i-14      accessories  B-class
```

When user search in 'brand' as 'BMW' and ENTER values should be passed like

```
   select *,'Primary' "type"  from dev.sales where %brand% = %'BMW'%
```

and When user search in 'agency' as 'apple' and ENTER values should be passed like

```
   select *,'Primary' "type"  from dev.sales where %agency% = %'apple'%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a function that uses dynamic SQL. Assuming that your table is called `the_table` then here it is.

```sql
create or replace function dynamic_search(column_name text, search_value text)
returns setof the_table language plpgsql as
$$
declare 
    DYNSQL constant text := 'SELECT * FROM the_table where %I = $1';
begin
    return query execute format(DYNSQL, column_name) using search_value;
end;
$$;
```

And then query

```
select *, 'Primary' as "type" 
from dynamic_search('brand', 'BMW');
```

Please note that this function is SQL injection prone.